# how are things being passed to onClick function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I was reviewing a code there user have done something like this

```
<temp onClick={this.onSelected} />
```

where `onSelected` looks like this

```
onSelected = (id: string) => {
    [...]
}
```

How is `id: string` passed here?

Also, out of curiosity (not primary function). what will be the difference between

```
onClick={() => this.onSelected()}
```

and

```
onClick={this.onSelected}
```

Comment: It isn't unless you're using a custom onClick. Normally onClick receives a React SyntheticEvent object when the user clicks on the underlying DOM element. NB your version with the arrow function discards the event completely.

Comment: looks like it's not being passed. only the event would be passed by default.

Comment: All these questions are answered in [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html)

Answer (score 6):

The component `<temp>` probably has some code similar to

```
props.onClick("some-id");
```

Which in turn will call the `onSelected` function with `id: string = "some-id"`

Comment: there is second part to the question as well. Would love if you could answer it as well

Comment: @anny123 see my comment above

Comment: In your second case, anything that `<temp>` passes into the passed `props.onClick` is ignored entirely